# make a live clock with existing time in div with javascript

Tags: javascript

ok lets say we have a website that need a realtime time;

example :

`<div id="updatetime">21:12:52</div>`

each seconds update hours:m:second.

what i have in minds using the `interval function` to do long pool and add the sec +1 if to 60 then add + 1 to m and same as hours. but is there a function already solving this problem?

**how do you make this `21:12:52` a moving real clock with javascript that updates each seconds?**

i have search google, stackoverflow, many of them tells us how to make the current real time datetime from javascript. but none from an existing time. if there is please do insert the link.

Comment: What do you mean a existing time?

Comment: 21:12:52(existing time) to 21:12:53 each seconds add the time to the div

Comment: Take a look to this TimeSpan class: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/62852/JavaScript-DateTime-and-TimeSpan-Wrappers

Comment: existing time means whatever is set on the user's computer?

Comment: existing time means whatever is set on the div, sorry for the ambiguty, i want the div to be a live clock

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It can be as easy as this:

```
setInterval(function(){
    document.getElementById("updatetime").innerHTML = (new Date()).toLocaleTimeString();
}, 1000);
```

Or use [the other Date methods](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) to fine-tune your output.

**Update**

I only now realized that OP was asking not about incrementing an element with the *current* time but with a *predetermined* time.

That's less trivial, but here is a solution that should fit the original question:

```
function increment_time_element(element, delay) {
    var interval, last,
        time_pattern = /(\d+):(\d+):(\d+)/,
        start = element.innerHTML.match(time_pattern),
        then = new Date;

    then.setHours  (parseInt(start[1], 10) || 0);
    then.setMinutes(parseInt(start[2], 10) || 0);
    then.setSeconds(parseInt(start[3], 10) || 0);

    function now() {
        return Date.now ? Date.now() : (new Date).getTime();
    }

    last = now();

    interval = setInterval(function () {
        var current = now();
        // correct for any interval drift by using actual difference
        then.setTime(then.getTime() + current - last)
        last = current;
        element.innerHTML = then.toString().match(time_pattern)[0];
    }, delay || 1000);

    return {cancel: function() { clearInterval(interval) }};
}

// Usage:
var incrementing_time =
    increment_time_element(document.getElementById("updatetime"));

// Then, if you want to cancel:
incrementing_time.cancel();
```

Comment: new date(existing time) maybe?

Comment: With no arguments, the Date constructor returns the current date/time.  toLocaleTimeString() gives something like "09:00:43" or "09:00:43 AM".

Comment: Be aware that `toLocaleString` [behaves differently depends by OS and User's settings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleTimeString), so if it's mandatory display the time in the format 'hh:mm:ss', it can't be used because there is no guarantee.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't need a very high fidelity, you can use this way:

```
​var container  = document.getElementById("updatetime").firstChild;
var values = container.nodeValue.split(":");

// Because there is only a datetime specified, I assume is the current date
var now = new Date();
var time = new Date(now.getFullYear(), now.getMonth(), now.getDate(),
                    values[0], values[1], values​[2]).getTime();

setInterval(function() {
    time += 1000;
    var date = new Date(time);
    var values = [date.getHours(), date.getMinutes(), date.getSeconds()];

    for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        if (values[i] < 10)
            values[i] = "0" + values[i];

    container.nodeValue = values.join(":");
}, 1000);
```

If you want to be more in sync with the current computer clock, then I suggest to you to use `setTimeout` and adjust the `delay` argument with the proper elapsed time.

**Update**: due the comments, it seems the elements to update are not only one and multiple, and the code is using jQuery. Here an approach that works for multiple elements using `class` to identify them:

```
var containers  = $(".updatetime");
var times = [];
var now = new Date();

containers.each(function(index, node) {
    var values = $(node).text().split(":");

    times[index] = new Date(
        now.getFullYear(), now.getMonth(), now.getDate(),
        values[0], values[1], values[2]).getTime();
});

setInterval(function() {
    containers.each(function(index, node) {
        times[index] += 1000;

        var date = new Date(times[index]);
        var values = [date.getHours(), date.getMinutes(), date.getSeconds()];

        for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++)
            if (values[i] < 10)
                values[i] = "0" + values[i];

        $(node).text(values.join(":"));
    });

}, 1000);
```

Comment: works great!, the only problem that it doesnt update all the ids. updatetime.

Comment: the `id` has to be unique, that's why is called "id": to identify one specific element. There is an attribute called [name](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.name), where the same value can be associate to multiple elements, but it doesn't apply to `div`. My suggestion is using the `class` attribute, so you will have `<div class='updatetime'>`. Then you can use [querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Document.querySelectorAll) where supported, or using library like Sizzle or jQuery where is not, and handle an array of "container" objects instead of only one.

Comment: im using jquery, heres what ive done http://pastebin.com/NCehgm7P somehow it work with all the class, but they are all the same value.

Comment: That's because you have to take in account multiple containers, therefore multiples different values, and `time`. You can still have one `setInterval`, but you have to add a loop to handle all containers. In my code above, it means at least that `container` and `time` variables have to be arrays (you can still use one `values` in a loop to convert the string in datetime).

Answer (score 2):

If your after a realtime clock that ticks along, take a look at the code I used when I created a "flip clock".
I split each digit into a seperate individual digit to use for graphic placement within the clock, but if you strip it down you will have just text that updates.

[Javascript Flip Clock](http://www.visualblissmedia.com/projects/clock)

Comment: link doesn't work.  I did find another Flip Clock:  http://flipclockjs.com/

Answer (score 2):

using HTML `canvas`

code:

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var radius = canvas.height / 2;
ctx.translate(radius, radius);
radius = radius * 0.90
setInterval(drawClock, 1000);

function drawClock() {
  drawFace(ctx, radius);
  drawNumbers(ctx, radius);
  drawTime(ctx, radius);
}

function drawFace(ctx, radius) {
  var grad;
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(0, 0, radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
  ctx.fillStyle = 'white';
  ctx.fill();
  grad = ctx.createRadialGradient(0, 0, radius * 0.95, 0, 0, radius * 1.05);
  grad.addColorStop(0, '#333');
  grad.addColorStop(0.5, 'white');
  grad.addColorStop(1, '#333');
  ctx.strokeStyle = grad;
  ctx.lineWidth = radius * 0.1;
  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(0, 0, radius * 0.1, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
  ctx.fillStyle = '#333';
  ctx.fill();
}

function drawNumbers(ctx, radius) {
  var ang;
  var num;
  ctx.font = radius * 0.15 + "px arial";
  ctx.textBaseline = "middle";
  ctx.textAlign = "center";
  for (num = 1; num < 13; num++) {
    ang = num * Math.PI / 6;
    ctx.rotate(ang);
    ctx.translate(0, -radius * 0.85);
    ctx.rotate(-ang);
    ctx.fillText(num.toString(), 0, 0);
    ctx.rotate(ang);
    ctx.translate(0, radius * 0.85);
    ctx.rotate(-ang);
  }
}

function drawTime(ctx, radius) {
  var now = new Date();
  var hour = now.getHours();
  var minute = now.getMinutes();
  var second = now.getSeconds();
  //hour
  hour = hour % 12;
  hour = (hour * Math.PI / 6) +
    (minute * Math.PI / (6 * 60)) +
    (second * Math.PI / (360 * 60));
  drawHand(ctx, hour, radius * 0.5, radius * 0.07);
  //minute
  minute = (minute * Math.PI / 30) + (second * Math.PI / (30 * 60));
  drawHand(ctx, minute, radius * 0.8, radius * 0.07);
  // second
  second = (second * Math.PI / 30);
  drawHand(ctx, second, radius * 0.9, radius * 0.02);
}

function drawHand(ctx, pos, length, width) {
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.lineWidth = width;
  ctx.lineCap = "round";
  ctx.moveTo(0, 0);
  ctx.rotate(pos);
  ctx.lineTo(0, -length);
  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.rotate(-pos);
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="400" height="400" style="background-color:#333">
</canvas>
```

Answer (score 0):

> you can do it with below code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function startTime() {
    var today = new Date();
    var h = today.getHours();
    var m = today.getMinutes();
    var s = today.getSeconds();
    m = checkTime(m);
    s = checkTime(s);
    document.getElementById('txt').innerHTML =
    h + ":" + m + ":" + s;
    var t = setTimeout(startTime, 500);
}
function checkTime(i) {
    if (i < 10) {i = "0" + i};  // add zero in front of numbers < 10
    return i;
}
</script>
</head>

<body onload="startTime()">

<div id="txt"></div>

</body>
</html>
```